# Process in real time

Tags: real-time, interrupts, processor-speed, process

I am building a Pov Display using Raspberry pi 4 and a code written in Go. The raspberry pi has a sensor (btn) to know when it displays the code. The problem is my raspberry won't execute the code at same delay every detection of (btn), therefore I see dots and some time lines. I want just to make the raspberry pi display the code written in Go with same delay every detection to see just dots.
**is it possible to tell the raspberry to execute my process in real-time without interrupting** like execute the process in one core and use the others for system ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You Need to exclude one CPU from the Overall scheduling in your /boot/cmdline.txt, afterwards you can assign the process to it via

```
taskset
```

as you already found out. To exclude a CPU, add the boot Parameter

```
isolcpus=N
```

The Number (N) is 0-based.